# Need help debugging Java code (EJML library)

Tags: java, ejml

Can someone help me find the bug in the following code. I receive a Java exception, but I have no idea why it occurs. Thanks for your attention! The description of the exception is as follows:

```
>    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>       at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
>       at org.ejml.data.DenseMatrix64F.set(Unknown Source)
>       at org.ejml.data.DenseMatrix64F.<init>(Unknown Source)
>       at org.ejml.simple.SimpleMatrix.<init>(Unknown Source)
>       at test1.<clinit>(test1.java:14)
```

for this code:

```
    import org.ejml.simple.SimpleMatrix;
    import java.lang.Math;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class test1 {
        class testcase3 {
            public testcase3() {
                Mkt = 100000;
                E1name = new SimpleMatrix(2, 5, true, -10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 1, 2, 3,
                        4, 5);
                E1name2 = new SimpleMatrix(2, 5, true, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -10, -5, 0,
                        5, 10);
                E2name = new SimpleMatrix(2, 2, true, 1, 3, 1, 2);
                E2name2 = new SimpleMatrix(2, 2, true, 1, 2, 1, 3);
                EM1 = new SimpleMatrix(2, 5, true, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                EM2 = new SimpleMatrix(2, 2, true, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                T = new SimpleMatrix(2, 2, true, 0, 0, 0, 0);
                Pa = new SimpleMatrix(1, 2, true, 0, 0);
                Position = 0;
            }

            public double Mkt;
            public SimpleMatrix E1name;
            public SimpleMatrix E2name;
            public SimpleMatrix E1name2;
            public SimpleMatrix E2name2;
            public SimpleMatrix EM1;
            public SimpleMatrix EM2;
            public SimpleMatrix T;
            public SimpleMatrix Pa;
            public int Position;

            public int newBidAsk(double bidPrice, double askPrice) {
                // log("I received a new Top-of-Book update, bid=" + bidPrice +
                // ", offer=" + askPrice);

                // data transformation
                double newMkt = (bidPrice + askPrice) / 2;
                double Grow = newMkt - Mkt;
                double Spread = (askPrice - bidPrice) / 2;

                SimpleMatrix seq = new SimpleMatrix(1, 2, true, Grow, Spread);
                SimpleMatrix z = new SimpleMatrix(1, 2, true, 0, 0);

                z.set(0, 0, Nametrans(seq.getIndex(0, 0), E1name));
                z.set(0, 1, Nametrans(seq.getIndex(0, 1), E2name));
                int act = 0;

                // parameter updating
                SimpleMatrix Px = Hmmupdate(Pa, z, EM1, EM2);
                SimpleMatrix newPa = Hmmpredict(Px, T);
                SimpleMatrix E1n = Hmmempredict(newPa, EM1, EM2, 5);
                SimpleMatrix E2n = Hmmempredict(newPa, EM1, EM2, 2);
                SimpleMatrix E = Eab(newMkt, E1n, E2n, E1name2, E2name2);
                int E1 = E.getIndex(0, 0);
                int E2 = E.getIndex(0, 1);

                // action
                if (Position == 0) {
                    int L = (int) Math.max(0,
                            Math.max(E1 - askPrice, bidPrice - E2));
                    switch (L) {
                    case 1:
                        act = 0;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        act = 1;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        act = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (Position == -1) {
                    int L = (int) Math.max(-askPrice, -E1);
                    switch (L) {
                    case 1:
                        act = 1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        act = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                } else if (Position == 1) {
                    int L = (int) Math.max(bidPrice, E2);
                    switch (L) {
                    case 1:
                        act = -1;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        act = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                Position = act + Position;
                // log("The act is " + Position);
                return Position;
            }

            public SimpleMatrix Eab(double Mkt, SimpleMatrix E1, SimpleMatrix E2,
                    SimpleMatrix E1name2, SimpleMatrix E2name2) {
                SimpleMatrix Easkbid = new SimpleMatrix(1, 2, true, Mkt, Mkt);
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                        Easkbid.set(0, 0,
                                Easkbid.getIndex(0, 0) + (Nametrans(i, E1name2))
                                        * E1.getIndex(0, i) * E2.getIndex(0, j));
                        Easkbid.set(0, 1,
                                Easkbid.getIndex(0, 1) + (Nametrans(i, E2name2))
                                        * E1.getIndex(0, i) * E2.getIndex(0, j));
                    }
                }
                return Easkbid;
            }

            public SimpleMatrix Hmmempredict(SimpleMatrix Pxkla, SimpleMatrix EM1,
                    SimpleMatrix EM2, int length) {
                SimpleMatrix E = new SimpleMatrix(1, length, true);
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                        E.set(1,
                                j,
                                E.getIndex(1, j) + EM2.getIndex(i, j)
                                        * Pxkla.getIndex(1, i));
                    }
                }
                E = normalize(E);
                return E;
            }

            public SimpleMatrix Hmmpredict(SimpleMatrix Pxk, SimpleMatrix T) {
                SimpleMatrix Pxkla = new SimpleMatrix(1, 2, true, 0, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                        Pxkla.set(0, i, Pxkla.getIndex(0, i) + Pxkla.getIndex(0, j)
                                * T.getIndex(j, i));
                    }
                }
                Pxkla = normalize(Pxkla);
                return Pxkla;
            }

            public SimpleMatrix Hmmupdate(SimpleMatrix Pxka, SimpleMatrix zk,
                    SimpleMatrix EM1, SimpleMatrix EM2) {
                SimpleMatrix Pxk = new SimpleMatrix(1, 2, true, 0, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    Pxk.set(0,
                            i,
                            (Pxka.getIndex(0, i)
                                    * EM1.getIndex(i, zk.getIndex(0, 0)) * EM2
                                    .getIndex(i, zk.getIndex(0, 1))));
                }
                Pxk = normalize(Pxk);
                return Pxk;
            }

            public SimpleMatrix normalize(SimpleMatrix B) {
                double temp = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < B.numCols(); i++) {
                    temp = B.getIndex(0, i);
                }
                SimpleMatrix A = B;
                for (int j = 0; j < A.numCols(); j++) {
                    A.set(0, j, B.getIndex(0, j) / temp);
                }
                return A;
            }

            public double Nametrans(double a, SimpleMatrix Nama) {
                int n = Nama.numCols();
                double b = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                    if (a == Nama.getIndex(0, i)) {
                        b = Nama.getIndex(1, i);
                    }
                }
                return b;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            double bid = s.nextDouble();
            double ask = s.nextDouble();
            testcase3 tc3;
            int act = tc3.newBidAsk(bid, ask);
            System.out.printf("%d", act);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack traces are great, they tell you the very line - or the very line after - an error occurs.  The only thing hinky I can see about your code is possible the negative numbers; try making your matrix without them and see if that clears up the error.  If it does, you could try passing real doubles there instead of integers that have to be converted by the runtime.

And, if it does, the library writers should have mentioned it in their javadoc, or perhaps you've discovered a (horrors!) major bug in their code.